# Dunn index value is zero what is this meaning?

Tags: cluster-analysis

In K-means algorithm when `k=5` I got Dunn index value 0.05 if `k=6` I got Dunn value 0. according to c-index `k=5` is good quality but Dunn value is decreasing then how can I interpret this?

Answer (score 0):

Something is completely broken in your code.

A Dunn index of 0 should only arise if every cluster has a second cluster at distance 0. But these then should be merged.

Furthermore, a distance of 0 should only arise if the clusters are all duplicate points. So by that, your data set would have at most 3 different points.

So your code probably is bad.

Comment: x<-matrix(total_data$`Average Price`,ncol=2)
> data<-kmeans (total_data$`Average Price`,2)
> c1<-intCriteria (x, data$cluster, c("C_index","Dunn") this is the code i have prepaired for dunn index is this wrong?

Comment: What is the purpose of `ncol=2`?

Comment: intCriteria (traj, part, crit) is function form of internal cluster indices.Here 'traj' argument is the matrix of observations.So, I have taken my variable in the matrix form with the number of columns 2. is this right form or not?

Comment: Where does that column come from? What are the values?

Comment: matrix(data = NA, nrow  , ncol  , byrow = FALSE,
       dimnames = NULL) generally this is function for creating matrix. So I have taken ncol=2. I am thinking of that matrix is a variable matrix. so 'total_data$Average Price ' variable is created 2 column  matrix hare.

Comment: [,1]   [,2]
   [1,]  446.18 122.31
   [2,]  453.44 128.98
   [3,]  455.06 128.08
   [4,]  458.46 128.38
   [5,]  457.22 132.85
   [6,]  454.96 142.01
   [7,]  446.88 143.60
   [8,]  452.99 143.13
   [9,]  456.91 139.11
  [10,]  469.33 143.09
  [11,]  476.54 141.94
  [12,]  483.42 145.12
  [13,]  487.69 144.44
  [14,]  483.72 146.16
  [15,]  455.00 147.88
  [16,]  444.75 144.57
  [17,]  449.00 146.05 like this 2730 values. i got 500 rows and 1360 rows are omitted. i got like this

Comment: But you only had one column? So you probably messed up all your data.

Comment: yes, I have only one column.So is that my code correct ?. I got Dunn index value is 0 at k=6 is this correct?

Comment: Ok, I got it I have to take ncol=1 in my coding, right.